# Mock async function in imported module

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, mocking, ts-jest

How can I spy on an async function in an imported module?

```
jest.mock('snowflake-promise');
import { Snowflake } from 'snowflake-promise';

describe('Snowflake', () => {
    let snowflakeMocked: any;

    beforeEach(async () => {
        snowflakeMocked = Snowflake as jest.Mocked<typeof Snowflake>;         
    });

    test('Snowflake is...', async () => {
        jest.spyOn(Snowflake, 'execute').mockResolvedValue(new Promise<void>());
```

`Argument of type '"execute"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.`

```
"snowflake-promise": "^4.2.0",
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import { Snowflake } from 'snowflake-promise';
import { mockDeep } from 'jest-mock-extended';

describe('Snowflake', () => {
    let snowflakeMocked: DeepMockProxy<Snowflake>;

    beforeEach(async () => {
        snowflakeMocked = mockDeep<Snowflake>();         
    });

    test('Snowflake is...', async () => {
        snowflakeMocked.execute.mockResolvedValue(Promise<void>.resolve());
    });
}
```

Comment: I edited it accordingly, please see if this works. Please also make sure to call jest.mock after actually importing Snowflake. @Hoppe

Comment: oh... I think I had the exact same issue with mocking something similarly and I initially used jest.Mocked but it didn't work out for me either so I ultimately went with mockDeep from 'jest-mock-extended'... sry for the confusion @Hoppe

Comment: I edited my answer... apologies again for wasting some of your time...

Comment: No this is working great. TY. But how do I spy on it? expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(expected). Received number of calls: 0